# Insert http:// into text field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm just curious on how I input the http:// into a text field whilst a user is typing it in.

You see on some sites that have a text field with http:// already inserted, I take it I need to use Javascript or Jquery but I wanted to understand different ways of doing this with RoR.

Just an update on the javascript, here are the rails fields below:

```
<div><%= f.label :github %><br />
<%= f.url_field :github %></div>

<div><%= f.label :stackoverflow %><br />
<%= f.url_field :stackoverflow %></div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you could simulate this with a label having the same style of the textbox. For the user it would seems as if the textbox already had pre fixed `http://` at the beggining

Comment: `element.onkeyup = function () {
      var val = this.value
      ;
      this.value = val.indexOf('http://') ? 'http://' + val : val;
    };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished by changing the `value` of the textbox:

```
document.getElementById('yourTextField').value = 'http://'
```

Replace `yourTextField` with the ID of your Text Field.
This should be placed in the beginning, so that the TextField starts with `http://`.

If you want to see if it already has it when submitting, you could:

```
if(document.getElementById('yourTextField').indexOf('http://') == 0)
{
   continueFunction()
}else
{
   submitValue = 'http://' + document.getElementById('yourTextField').value
}
```

An easier way would just be setting `value` when defining the textBox.

Comment: How would I include this in an html page, <script></script> I'm not great with Javascript.

Comment: @ShaunFrostDukeJackson Correct, put it in a <script> tag in your HTML code (`<script>javascriptcodehere</script>`) which defaults to javascript on `type`

Comment: I've just updated my question, how would I insert it into a rails field.

Comment: @ShaunFrostDukeJackson Unfortunately, I don't know much about rails.

Answer (score 0):

You just put some javascript listening for an appropriate event (for example the text box getting focus) and then if the text box is empty insert http:// and move the cursor to the end.

I've also seen fancier things that do stuff like put "enter URL here" in the box greyed out then when you click remove that, set the colour back to black and enter the http://